# C# class representation for this json

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I need little help to create C# class to map below json response from FCM token info api (https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances):

```
{
   "application": "com.chrome.windows",
   "subtype": "wp:www.mydomain.com/#A1249A346-7458-45BB-A0F2-2AC4856BB-V2",
   "scope": "*",
   "authorizedEntity": "8212312155",
   "rel": {
      "topics": {
         "topic1": {
            "addDate": "2020-12-06"
         }
      }
   },
   "platform": "BROWSER"
}
```

Where **topic1** is not the property name, rather a value and **topics** which is a property name contains the list of topics.

I am actually not sure how to represent the **topics** in above json.

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, Topic> Topics {get;set;}`

Comment: Visual Studio **Paste** menu  => **Paste Special -> Paste Json As Classes**

Comment: If you want to have better naming of properties you can change them as you like, and add [JsonProperty("topic1")] above the property. So you don't get any error with Serialization

Answer (score 0):

It is Dictionary format.

`public Dictionary<string, Topic> Topics {get;set;}`

The class is like below:

```
public class Root
{
    public string application { get; set; }
    public string subtype { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public string authorizedEntity { get; set; }
    public Rel rel { get; set; }
    public string platform { get; set; }
}

public class Rel
{
    public Dictionary<string, Topic> topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public string addDate { get; set; }
}
```

The above json can be serialized from the below model:

```
var root = new Root
{
    application = "com.chrome.windows",
    subtype = "wp:www.mydomain.com/#A1249A346-7458-45BB-A0F2-2AC4856BB-V2",
    scope = "*",
    authorizedEntity = "8212312155",
    rel = new Rel
    {
        topics = new Dictionary<string, Topic>
        {
            { 
                "topic1", 
                new Topic
                { 
                    addDate = "2020-12-06" 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    platform = "BROWSER"
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
    public class Topic1    {
        public string addDate { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Topics    {
        public Topic1 topic1 { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Rel    {
        public Topics topics { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public string application { get; set; } 
        public string subtype { get; set; } 
        public string scope { get; set; } 
        public string authorizedEntity { get; set; } 
        public Rel rel { get; set; } 
        public string platform { get; set; } 
    }
```

https://json2csharp.com/

If you are sure that topics contain unique topic names , so use Dictionary, if not sure, then List

Comment: The Topics contain unique topic names, but Topics can contains any number of topics. So, we cannot have a class like Topic1

Comment: @Ivan I downvoted.. It is easy to convert some given Json string 1:1 using online tools, but it does not answer the question. Topics can contain multiple named items, which cannot be represented directly. It actually requires a **Dictionary<string,string>** of  items.. It will have a single entry for above Json string, with a key named "Topic1". Paul Michaels wrote a nice tutorial how to parse your Json string and add dictionary items underway. for each of the the Topics: https://www.pmichaels.net/2016/12/26/manually-parsing-a-json-string-using-json-net/

Comment: I understood what Ahmed want a little bit later on :) Of course it is a good idea to use dictionary, but I had no time to update the code. So your minus one is correct.